# Sharepoint 2007 filter list to show latest update per employee

Tags: sharepoint-2007

We have a very simple list with in/out status.  Each time an employee clocks in or out it adds a record to the list.  How can I filter the list to only show the last update by each employee? It seems we should be able to do something like a MAX(modified) per user, but how would that accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue here is the solution:

Create a new view based on all items.
Group by Employee
Sort by Modified (Descending)
Item Limit = 1
Show all items without folders (in folder settings)
Be sure to set it to expand all items.